# dynamic crm search in notes text

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I want to enable quick search on records and include regarding notes on that search. 
I am able to do it through advanced find but look for a way to it with quick search.

I am using dynamic crm 2013 on premise.

Any suggestions for that issue ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to create a custom quickfind search page and attach it to the sitemap.
Inside the search page you can easily get the actual entity quickfind fetch and layout xml or create your custom advance find query and [tailor the results into an advanced find iframe](http://totbcrm.blogspot.com/2014/08/display-custom-fetch-in-grid.html).